Chequeo de base válida en conversor de bases
Tengo este programa en PSeInt. La conversión de decimal a binario y viceversa funciona bien, pero si la base binara o decimal se ingresa incorrectamente (ejemplo, 2 para binario) da resultado 0 cuando no debería escribir texto en pantalla. ¿Cómo puedo corregir este error?
    Proceso ConvertidorNumerico
    Definir input, Numero, resultado Como Cadenas;
    Definir DeBase, tobase Como Entero;
    
    Escribir "Ingrese el número a convertir: ";
    Leer input;
    Numero <- input;
    
    Escribir "Ingrese la base del número (Binario = 2, = 10): ";
    Leer DeBase;
    
    Escribir "Ingrese la base a convertir (Binario = 2, = 10): ";
    Leer tobase;
    
    // Verificación de la validez del número
    Si NoEsValido(Numero, DeBase) Entonces
        Escribir "El número ingresado no es válido para la base ", DeBase;
    FinSi
    
    resultado <- Convertir(Numero, DeBase, tobase);
    Si resultado <> "" Entonces
        Escribir "Resultado: ", resultado;      
    FinSi
FinProceso

Funcion Retorno <- DecToBin(DecNum)
    Definir BinStr Como Caracter;
    Definir index Como Entero;
    Definir Retorno Como Cadena;
    BinStr <- "";
    index <- 0;
    
    Si DecNum = 0 Entonces
        Retorno <- "0";
    FinSi
    
    Mientras DecNum <> 0 Hacer
        Si trunc(DecNum) Mod 2 = 1 Entonces
            BinStr <- concatenar("1",BinStr);
        Sino
            BinStr <- concatenar("0",BinStr);
        FinSi
        DecNum <- Trunc(DecNum / 2);
    FinMientras
    
    Retorno <- BinStr;
FinSubProceso

SubProceso Retorno <- BinToDec(BinStr)
    Definir mult Como Real;
    Definir DecNum Como Real;
    Definir len, i, Retorno Como Entero;
    mult <- 1;
    DecNum <- 0;
    
    len <- Longitud(BinStr);
    
    Para i <- len - 1 Hasta 0 Con Paso -1 Hacer
        Si SubCadena(BinStr, i, i) = "1" Entonces
            DecNum <- DecNum + mult;
        FinSi
        mult <- mult * 2;
    FinPara
    
    Retorno <- DecNum;
FinSubProceso

SubProceso Retorno <- posicion(subcad, cad)
    Definir i, encontrado, retorno Como Entero;
    encontrado <- 0;
    
    Para i <- 0 Hasta Longitud(cad)-1 Hacer
        Si Subcadena(cad, i, Longitud(subcad)) = subcad Entonces
            encontrado <- i;
            i <- Longitud(cad) + 1; // Salir del bucle
        FinSi
    FinPara
    Retorno <- encontrado;
FinSubProceso

SubProceso Retorno <- Verificar(valor, bag) //Revisar
    Definir i, retorno Como Entero;
    Para i <- 0 Hasta Longitud(valor) - 1 Hacer
        Si Posicion(Subcadena(valor, i, 1), bag) = 0 Entonces
            Retorno <- 0;
        FinSi
    FinPara
    Retorno <- 1;
FinSubProceso

Funcion Retorno <- NoEsValido(valor, DeBase) // Función para verificar validez
    Definir retorno Como Entero;
    retorno <- 1; // Asumir que es válido por defecto
    
    Segun DeBase Hacer
        2:
            Si Verificar(valor, "01") = 0 Entonces
                retorno <- 0; // No válido
            FinSi
        10:
            Si Verificar(valor, "0123456789") = 0 Entonces
                retorno <- 0; // No válido
            FinSi
    FinSegun
    
    Retorno <- retorno;
FinFuncion

SubProceso Retorno <- Convertir(numToConvert, DeBase, tobase) //Revisado
    Definir result Como Caracter;
    Definir retorno Como Cadena;
    result <- "";
    
    Si DeBase = tobase Entonces
        Retorno <- numToConvert;
    FinSi
    
    // Continuar con las conversiones si es válido
    Segun DeBase Hacer
        2:
            Segun tobase Hacer
                10:
                    Retorno <- convertirATexto(BinToDec(numToConvert));
            FinSegun
        10:
            Segun tobase Hacer
                2:
                    Retorno <- DecToBin(convertiraNumero(numToConvert));
            FinSegun
    FinSegun
FinSubProceso


Nota: Primera vez que veo psint pero dado lo aburrido que estaba me animo a responder. Digo esto como aclaración, porque vi que hay configuraciones (perfiles) que pueden cambiar el comportamiento, no sé si estaremos usando la misma.

Tienes muchos errores
Si NoEsValido(Numero, DeBase) Entonces
   Escribir "El número ingresado no es válido para la base ", DeBase;
FinSi

La función NoEsValido retorna un 0 o 1 no retorna un booleano, por lo que esa condición nunca se cumple. Debería ser Si NoEsValido(Numero, DeBase) = 1

1) Función NoEsValido
Si haces un pequeño test, puedes ver que:
Escribir NoEsValido("10",10); // Imprime 1
Escribir NoEsValido("AA",10); // Imprime 1


Existen lenguajes que 0/1 es equivalente a false/true, pero aun en ellos es preferible usar false/true. En este caso, por lo menos no mi configuración, es casi obligatorio, por lo que esta función debería retornar un booleano
Preguntar en negativo es confuso: ¿El Sol NO es caliente? ¿si?¿no?.- En cambio ¿El Sol ES caliente? la respuesta es clara. Tu función debería llamarse EsValido
Puedes usas la misma función para verificar si la base es valida

Funcion Retorno <- EsValido(valor, DeBase) // Función para verificar validez
    Segun DeBase Hacer
        2: Retorno <- Verificar(valor, "01"); 
        10:  Retorno <- Verificar(valor, "0123456789"); 
        De Otro Modo: Retorno <- Falso;
    FinSegun
FinFuncion

2) Función Posicion
Test:
Escribir posicion("2", "1235"); // Imprime 1 -> bien
Escribir posicion("1", "123"); // Imprime 0  -> bien
Escribir posicion("A", "123"); // Imprime 0  -> mal
Escribir posicion("7", "12345678"); // Imprime 0  -> mal

Fíjate en el segundo y tercer caso, en ambos retorna 0. Tu configuración indica que los índices comienzan en cero, por tanto, esa es la primera posición, que para el segundo caso es correcto 1 se encuentra en la posición 0 en el string 123. Pero es que, además, cuando no encuentras la posición (como en el tercer caso) también retornas cero. Habitualmente los lenguajes para este tipo de función retornan -1 cuando no se encuentra y es lo que haremos.
Además, estas usando incorrectamente la función Subcadena, el tercer argumento de esta función es la posición final (inclusiva), no es el largo como intuyo estas usándola tu
//Esto tienes tu
Subcadena(cad, i, Longitud(subcad))

//Así debería ser
Subcadena(cad, i, Longitud(subcad) + i - 1)

Este punto es el que causa el error en el cuarto caso del test, por tanto la función debería quedar así
Funcion Retorno <- Posicion(subcad, cad)
    Definir i Como Entero;
    Retorno <- -1;
    Para i <- 0 Hasta Longitud(cad)-1 Hacer
        Si Subcadena(cad, i, i+ Longitud(subcad)-1) = subcad Entonces
            Retorno <- i;
            i<-Longitud(cad);
        FinSi
    FinPara
FinSubProceso

3) Función Verificar
Luego de los cambios realizado a las otras 2 funciones, necesitamos modificar la función Verificar a:
Funcion Retorno <- Verificar(valor, bag) //Revisar
    Definir i Como Entero;
    Retorno <- Verdadero;
    Para i <- 0 Hasta Longitud(valor) - 1 Hacer
        Si Posicion(Subcadena(valor, i, i), bag) = -1 Entonces
            Retorno <- Falso;
            i<-Longitud(valor)
        FinSi
    FinPara
FinFuncion


Corregido estos temas, ahora puedes hacer:
Si EsValido(Numero, DeBase) Entonces
    resultado <- Convertir(Numero, DeBase, tobase);
    Si resultado <> "" Entonces
        Escribir "Resultado: ", resultado;      
    FinSi
SiNo
    Escribir "El número ingresado no es válido para la base ", DeBase;
FinSi

Te aclaro que no revisé el resto de las funciones

Estoy usando índices de arrgos y cadenas en 0

¿Hay alguna forma de que en la función posicion el retorno quede debajo de las sentencias pero sin afectar el resultado? Por una cuestión lógica, primero se hacen los cálculos y después se hace el retorno.

@AlejandroCaro Como comentaba al inicio de mi respuesta, esta vez fue la primera vez que hago algo en PsiInt.  Lo que pude entender, es que la funciones no tienen retorno, al menos no como los "lenguajes decentes"; por ejemplo no puedes hacer early return. En cambio, tiene un sistema de asignación al nombre de la función (Visual Basic también tiene este sistema junto con el return normal). Esto implica un paradigma diferente, una forma de hacer las cosas distintas, por lo que creo que la "cuestión lógica" no aplica implementarla.

En cualquier caso, la solución sería utilizar una variable auxiliar, tal como tú lo venias haciendo en tus funciones. Yo considero que es enredar el código, pero cada uno con sus gustos :P
